# ngx-formly password visibility toggle - angular

Tags: javascript, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-formly

I want to add a custom input field using ngx-formly where I can toggle the password(eye). I have two fields in the form email/username and password. I tried some kinds of stuff, but not working for me

How to make a form with these two fields?

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: i do not have the code right now, can you please make a field with ngx-formly that have an eye icon at the start, on clicking on it , the password should show and vice versa

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.